# How to fix warning "predefined types 'Action t1,t2,t3' is defined in multiple assemblies" while publishing asp.net mvc project?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, warnings, publish

When I want to publish my asp.net mvc project, I get no errors, but I have some warnings. I have searched about it a lot, but I did not find anything about it. I do not understand the meaning of this warning. Do I need to update something to solve that? The following warning has been repeated 15 times. I would be grateful if you could help me.

> 1>ASPNETCOMPILER(0,0): Warning CS1685: The predefined type Action t1, t2, t3 is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

I do not understand what `Action<T1, T2, T3>` means? What should I do to resolve this warning?